# How to get youngest matching record in SQL?

Tags: sql-server

i am trying to create a table that tells me how long a product has aged until the date of the purchase.  The code itself works, but I only want the youngest record to appear.

So far it matches the Order created with every historical receipt date of the product. However, I only want the youngest receipt date that is before Order created.

```
SELECT
OPF.Order_Number,
PD.[Product_Id],
PD.[Product_Title],
OPF.Order_Created,
MAX(R.[receipt_date]),
DATEDIFF(day, R.[receipt_date], OPF.Order_Created) AS 'Days Aged'

FROM [DataWarehouse].[dbo].[Product_D] PD (NOLOCK)

JOIN [DataWarehouse].[dbo].[Order_Product_F] OPF (NOLOCK)
    ON PD.Product_Key = OPF.Product_Key

LEFT JOIN [Supply_Chain].[dbo].[Receipt_Product] RP (NOLOCK)
    on PD.Product_Id = RP.product_id

JOIN [Supply_Chain].[dbo].[Receipt] R (NOLOCK)
    ON RP.receipt_id = R.receipt_id

WHERE
OPF.Order_Number IN ('xxxxxxxx')
AND
R.[receipt_date] < OPF.Order_Created


GROUP BY 
OPF.Order_Number,
PD.[Product_Id],
PD.[Product_Title],
OPF.Order_Created,
R.[receipt_date]

ORDER BY
DATEDIFF(day, R.[receipt_date], OPF.Order_Created) ASC
```

I think I will have to do a sub query, but I am not quite sure where to start.

Comment: `SELECT TOP 1`.

Comment: Please add some sample data with expected output.

Comment: Thanks jahrl. That seems to have worked!  Did not think about that :0